# Getting the string values from a controller to the Visual force component

Tags: javascript, salesforce, apex

I want a value from the controller in the component using JavaScript, but I am new to this so I don't know how to achieve it. This is my controller class:

```
public with sharing class DragAndDropMultipleDirect
{
    Public string orgID {get;set;}
    Public string userID {get;set;}
    Public string s3path {get;set;}
    public DragAndDropMultipleDirect()
    {

    }

    public String path()
    {
        String orgID = UserInfo.getOrganizationId() ;
        String userID =UserInfo.getUserId();
        String s3path ='string/'+orgID+'/'+userID;
        system.debug('orgID ==== ???  '+s3path);
        return s3path;
    }
```

I want the value of s3path in the script of the component.

```
<apex:component Controller="DragAndDropMultipleDirect">
    <apex:attribute name="parentId" type="String" description="Parent record"/>
    <Script>
        function readfiles(files) {
            var path = **Here I want the value of s3Path**
            ----- code----
        }
    </Script>
</apex:component>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that s3Path should hold the value. Here is the modified controller and component:

```
public class DragAndDropMultipleDirect
{
    public string orgID {get;set;}
    public string userID {get;set;}
    public string s3path {get;set;}

    public DragAndDropMultipleDirect()
    {
        s3path = 'string/' + UserInfo.getOrganizationId() + '/' + UserInfo.getUserId();
    }
}
```

And the Visualforce component:

```
<apex:component Controller="DragAndDropMultipleDirect">
    <apex:attribute name="parentId" type="String" description="Parent record"/>

    <Script>
        function readfiles(files) {
            var path = '**Here I want the value of {!s3path}**';
        }
    </Script>
</apex:component>
```